# Excel chart, change axis tick's positions to specific integer values

Tags: charts, microsoft-excel-2016, label, axis

I'm trying to move the position of all axis ticks to integer values while trying to keep the real scale (min and max values) of the axis as decimals.

The current position of the ticks are: 6.8, 7.8, 8.8, ..., and I'm trying to change them to 7, 8, 9, ...which means the origin point (6.8) does not have label, but move the first tick and label to 7.

Changing the decimal places from 1 to 0 does not work because it would just give rounded numbers of decimals instead of move the ticks to real integer values. I'm using Excel for Mac version 16.39.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a result that you need? I guess a scatter could help you.

In following sample, I created 2 columns, X and Y and are coordinate values, the values of Y are label values that you need to shown on Y axis.

Using X and Y to create a a scatter, adjust the maximum and minimum that you want.

[image]

Then choose None for Label Position.

[image]

Right click the scatter > choose Add Data Labels. And then you could choose color or line type for the Line and Marker.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, Emily!

Comment: If my reply is helpful, could you please mark it as an answer? Thanks.